# Discord.py currency bot; Create bank account command only working for first person using the command. How to fix?

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.lower().startswith('.enroll'):
    dent = message.author.id
    bcall = message.author.display_name

    fart ={
    f"{dent}": [
    {
      "cash": 0,
      "bank": 0
    }
    ]
    }

    json_object = json.dumps(fart, indent = 3)

    with open("bank.json", "w") as outfile: 
      outfile.write(json_object)

    ebank = discord.Embed(title=f"{bcall}'s Enrollment", color=random.choice(colours))
    ebank.set_author(name='Eisendrache', icon_url='https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/803648238497824839/816356860369961021/eisendrache.png')
    ebank.add_field(name="User ID", value=dent, inline=False)
    ebank.add_field(name="Cash", value="0 :money_with_wings:", inline=False)
    ebank.add_field(name="Bank", value="0 :money_with_wings:", inline=False)
    ebank.set_image(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/817048944022257744/817993420366282772/BOT_BANK.jpeg")
    ebank.set_footer(text=f'Eisendrache • {(timestamp)}', icon_url='https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/803648238497824839/816356860369961021/eisendrache.png')
    await message.channel.send(embed=ebank)
```

JSON FILE:

```json
{
   "799335941160173609": [
      {
         "cash": 0,
         "bank": 0
      }
   ]
}
```

So when I use the command, the first person's information goes into the json file. But anyone after that who uses it, it doesn't work. Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to be doing is updating the json file every time a new user is created. If you create a new dictionary and write it to the file. the old data will be removed.

```py
async def on_message(message):
  #other stuff
  with open('bank.json', 'r') as f:
       bank_details = json.load(f) #use better names than fart
  if str(message.author.id) in bank_details:
       #user already exists
  else:
      #create new user
      bank_details[str(message.author.id)] = {} #details here
  with open('bank.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(bank_details, f, indent=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to the JSON file, then perhaps you should tell Python that's what you want.

```
    with open("bank.json", "a") as outfile: 
      outfile.write(json_object)
```

HOWEVER, there's a problem with that.  A file that has a series of separate JSON records is not a valid JSON file.  If you just want to remember these, that's fine.  But if you plan to read these later and JSON decode them, you have extra work to do.  That's why JSON is a poor choice for a database like this.